# Getting the same display names as in "Advanced display settings" panel with WinApi

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Using the same methods as in answers to other questions related to getting display names through WinApi (using `EnumDisplayDevicesW` while passing the device name as the first parameter, similarly to e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181064/enumdisplaydevices-vs-wmi-win32-desktopmonitor-how-to-detect-active-monitors?rq=1)), I've been able to achieve partial success. The issue I'm having is that I'm getting incomplete information. The "Advanced display settings" panel which can be accessed by right clicking on the desktop, selecting "Display settings", and then selecting "Advanced display settings" on the bottom displays the following displays:

```
DELL P2414H(DisplayPort)
AOC AG271QG
BenQ PJ
```

However, through the use of `EnumDisplayDevicesW` calls, I extracted the following:

```
AOC AG271QG
DELL P2414H(DisplayPort)
Generic PnP Monitor
```

While the order doesn't matter to me, the issue is that I'm getting "Generic PnP Monitor" rather than the more helpful "BenQ PJ" (which is not the exact model that I was hoping for, but still provides at least some information). What can I do to extract "BenQ PJ" rather than "Generic PnP Monitor" (preferably remaining within WinApi)?

Comment: Looks like you need nested calls see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/getting-information-on-a-display-monitor

Comment: The nested calls is what I already use (they're also implemented in the question I linked) - without them, I wouldn't get information on the other monitors (and instead just on the adapter, so the GPU). I'm sure that this API call won't get me any further. In fact, the same "Generic PnP Monitor" pops up when I click "Display adapter properties for Display 3" in the window I mentioned - so there are certainly 2 sources of different information (and `EnumDisplayDevicesW` apparently isn't the one I'm looking for).

Comment: Have you looked through the long combobox of device properties in the properties dialog of the monitor in Device Manager to see if the string you want appears somewhere there?

Comment: The screen's have no driver installed and therefore the actual device itself is running with the Generic PnP Monitor Driver. I think you'd better check it. Look in Device Manager and you will see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get Monitor information with **EDID**

EDID can be read with WMI

For example, test with *WmiOpenBlock* and so on, to reduce code of WMI in C++ =>

I get for my monitor :

```
Instance Name = DISPLAY\PHLC085\4&20634529&0&UID65793_0
User Friendly Name = 247ELH
Manufacturer Name = PHL
Product Code ID = C085
Serial Number ID = AU01307001613
```

Includes and defines =>

```
#define _CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <wmistr.h>
DEFINE_GUID(WmiMonitorID_GUID, 0x671a8285, 0x4edb, 0x4cae, 0x99,0xfe,0x69,0xa1,0x5c,0x48,0xc0,0xbc );
typedef struct WmiMonitorID {
    USHORT ProductCodeID[16];
    USHORT SerialNumberID[16];
    USHORT ManufacturerName[16];
    UCHAR WeekOfManufacture;
    USHORT YearOfManufacture;
    USHORT UserFriendlyNameLength;
    USHORT UserFriendlyName[1];
} WmiMonitorID, *PWmiMonitorID;
#define OFFSET_TO_PTR(Base, Offset) ((PBYTE)((PBYTE)Base + Offset))

typedef HRESULT(WINAPI*WOB) (IN LPGUID lpGUID, IN DWORD nAccess, OUT LONG*);
WOB WmiOpenBlock;
typedef HRESULT(WINAPI*WQAD) (IN LONG hWMIHandle, ULONG* nBufferSize, OUT UCHAR * pBuffer);
WQAD WmiQueryAllData;
typedef HRESULT(WINAPI*WCB) (IN LONG);
WCB WmiCloseBlock;
```

Test code =>

```
HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
LONG hWmiHandle;
PWmiMonitorID MonitorID;
HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary(L"Advapi32.dll");
WmiOpenBlock = (WOB)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "WmiOpenBlock");
WmiQueryAllData = (WQAD)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "WmiQueryAllDataW");
WmiCloseBlock = (WCB)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "WmiCloseBlock");
if (WmiOpenBlock != NULL && WmiQueryAllData && WmiCloseBlock)
{
    WCHAR pszDeviceId[256] = L"";
    hr = WmiOpenBlock((LPGUID)&WmiMonitorID_GUID, GENERIC_READ, &hWmiHandle);
    if (hr == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        ULONG nBufferSize = 0;
        UCHAR *pAllDataBuffer = 0;
        PWNODE_ALL_DATA pWmiAllData;
        hr = WmiQueryAllData(hWmiHandle, &nBufferSize, 0);
        if (hr == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            pAllDataBuffer = (UCHAR*)malloc(nBufferSize);
            hr = WmiQueryAllData(hWmiHandle, &nBufferSize, pAllDataBuffer);
            if (hr == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                while (1)
                {
                    pWmiAllData = (PWNODE_ALL_DATA)pAllDataBuffer;
                    if (pWmiAllData->WnodeHeader.Flags & WNODE_FLAG_FIXED_INSTANCE_SIZE)
                        MonitorID = (PWmiMonitorID)&pAllDataBuffer[pWmiAllData->DataBlockOffset];
                    else
                        MonitorID = (PWmiMonitorID)&pAllDataBuffer[pWmiAllData->OffsetInstanceDataAndLength[0].OffsetInstanceData];

                    ULONG nOffset = 0;
                    WCHAR *pwsInstanceName = 0;
                    nOffset = (ULONG)pAllDataBuffer[pWmiAllData->OffsetInstanceNameOffsets];
                    pwsInstanceName = (WCHAR*)OFFSET_TO_PTR(pWmiAllData, nOffset + sizeof(USHORT));
                    WCHAR wsText[255] = L"";
                    swprintf(wsText, L"Instance Name = %s\r\n", pwsInstanceName);
                    OutputDebugString(wsText);

                    WCHAR *pwsUserFriendlyName;
                    pwsUserFriendlyName = (WCHAR*)MonitorID->UserFriendlyName;
                    swprintf(wsText, L"User Friendly Name = %s\r\n", pwsUserFriendlyName);
                    OutputDebugString(wsText);

                    WCHAR *pwsManufacturerName;
                    pwsManufacturerName = (WCHAR*)MonitorID->ManufacturerName;
                    swprintf(wsText, L"Manufacturer Name = %s\r\n", pwsManufacturerName);
                    OutputDebugString(wsText);

                    WCHAR *pwsProductCodeID;
                    pwsProductCodeID = (WCHAR*)MonitorID->ProductCodeID;
                    swprintf(wsText, L"Product Code ID = %s\r\n", pwsProductCodeID);
                    OutputDebugString(wsText);

                    WCHAR *pwsSerialNumberID;
                    pwsSerialNumberID = (WCHAR*)MonitorID->SerialNumberID;
                    swprintf(wsText, L"Serial Number ID = %s\r\n", pwsSerialNumberID);
                    OutputDebugString(wsText);

                    if (!pWmiAllData->WnodeHeader.Linkage)
                        break;
                    pAllDataBuffer += pWmiAllData->WnodeHeader.Linkage;
                }
                free(pAllDataBuffer);
            }
        }
        WmiCloseBlock(hWmiHandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is right - "BenQ PJ" is apparently the user friendly name.

Comment: Be aware that a shifted pointer passed into `free()` is undefined behavior, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237449/how-to-safely-free-memory-using-a-pointer-which-has-been-adjusted). This code also produces a memory leak since `free()` is not called if `WmiQueryAllData()` fails.

Answer (score 2):

There is an official example code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig) that also seems to be able extract monitor name from EDID:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO> paths;
    vector<DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO> modes;
    UINT32 flags = QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS | QDC_VIRTUAL_MODE_AWARE;
    LONG result = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    do
    {
        // Determine how many path and mode structures to allocate
        UINT32 pathCount, modeCount;
        result = GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(flags, &pathCount, &modeCount);

        if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(result);
        }

        // Allocate the path and mode arrays
        paths.resize(pathCount);
        modes.resize(modeCount);

        // Get all active paths and their modes
        result = QueryDisplayConfig(flags, &pathCount, paths.data(), &modeCount, modes.data(), nullptr);

        // The function may have returned fewer paths/modes than estimated
        paths.resize(pathCount);
        modes.resize(modeCount);

        // It's possible that between the call to GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes and QueryDisplayConfig
        // that the display state changed, so loop on the case of ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER.
    } while (result == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);

    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(result);
    }

    // For each active path
    for (auto& path : paths)
    {
        // Find the target (monitor) friendly name
        DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME targetName = {};
        targetName.header.adapterId = path.targetInfo.adapterId;
        targetName.header.id = path.targetInfo.id;
        targetName.header.type = DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_NAME;
        targetName.header.size = sizeof(targetName);
        result = DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo(&targetName.header);

        if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(result);
        }

        // Find the adapter device name
        DISPLAYCONFIG_ADAPTER_NAME adapterName = {};
        adapterName.header.adapterId = path.targetInfo.adapterId;
        adapterName.header.type = DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_ADAPTER_NAME;
        adapterName.header.size = sizeof(adapterName);

        result = DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo(&adapterName.header);

        if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(result);
        }

        wcout
            << L"Monitor with name "
            << (targetName.flags.friendlyNameFromEdid ? targetName.monitorFriendlyDeviceName : L"Unknown")
            << L" is connected to adapter "
            << adapterName.adapterDevicePath
            << L" on target "
            << path.targetInfo.id
            << L"\n";
    }
}
```

On my Windows 11(10.0.22621) PC, copying it to main.cpp, compiling by running:

```
"Path\to\Visual\Studio\vcvars32.bat" // activate Visual Studio Command Prompt
"Path\to\Visual\Studio\cl.exe /EHsc User32.lib OneCoreUAP.lib main.cpp /link /subsystem:console
```

and then running the generated `main.exe` from command line will give:

```
Monitor with name GCU321HXA is connected to adapter \\?\PCI#VEN_10DE&DEV_24DC&SUBSYS_3F8417AA&REV_A1#4&12b1023e&0&0008#{5b45201d-f2f2-4f3b-85bb-30ff1f953599} on target 4356
Monitor with name Cintiq Pro_16 is connected to adapter \\?\PCI#VEN_10DE&DEV_24DC&SUBSYS_3F8417AA&REV_A1#4&12b1023e&0&0008#{5b45201d-f2f2-4f3b-85bb-30ff1f953599} on target 4352
```

which includes device names same as those shown in "Advanced display settings".

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite some time and the solution from **@Castorix** still works. I would like to extend his answer, give some perspectives and propose another solution for future readers. There are essentially three different ideas to access the user friendly name of a display.

1. Use Advapi32 WMI to access the processed EDID and extract the name. The approach clearly works like **@Castorix** showed but uses an undocumented interface to access the data. This is also the reason you have to load the functions yourself.
2. Use SetupAPI to find the raw EDID registry entry for all displays and extract the display name descriptor. This approach was the first I used and it's quite cumbersome. EDID has multiple versions with different guaranties, so you have to carefully check if the descriptor is supported (since EDID 1.3) and where it is located.
3. Use User32 QueryDisplayConfig to access the display device info including the friendly name. I like this solution the most because it uses documented functions and provides useful properties like the monitor handle (HMONITOR), the monitor index and device path of the display. This allows for easy access to a lot of additional information (e.g via `GetMonitorInfoW` for virtual monitor bounds).

The third solution produces the following results on my dual monitor setup (two ASUS VC239):

```
MONITOR[1]: ASUS VC239
Handle: 65537
DevicePath: \\?\DISPLAY#ACI23C4#7&26221e0f&2&UID256#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}

MONITOR[2]: ASUS VC239
Handle: 65539
DevicePath: \\?\DISPLAY#ACI23C4#7&26221e0f&2&UID260#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}
```

The implementation does ignore some return values, but never behaves faulty even if the api calls would fail. Depending on your requirements additional error handling could be introduced:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

struct MonitorQuery {
    const WCHAR* device_name;
    HMONITOR monitor;
    uint32_t index;
};

void enumerate_display_devices() {
    UINT32 query_flags = QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS;
    UINT32 path_count = 0, mode_count = 0;
    GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(query_flags, &path_count, &mode_count);
    std::vector<DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO> paths(path_count);
    std::vector<DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO> modes(mode_count);
    QueryDisplayConfig(query_flags, &path_count, paths.data(), &mode_count, modes.data(), nullptr);

    for (UINT32 i = 0; i < path_count; ++i) {
        const DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO& path = paths[i];

        DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME target_device = {};
        target_device.header.type = DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_NAME;
        target_device.header.size = sizeof(target_device);
        target_device.header.adapterId = path.targetInfo.adapterId;
        target_device.header.id = path.targetInfo.id;
        if (DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo(&target_device.header) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            continue;
        }
        DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_DEVICE_NAME source_device = {};
        source_device.header.type = DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_SOURCE_NAME;
        source_device.header.size = sizeof(source_device);
        source_device.header.adapterId = path.targetInfo.adapterId;
        source_device.header.id = path.sourceInfo.id;
        if (DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo(&source_device.header) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            continue;
        }
        MonitorQuery query = {};
        query.device_name = source_device.viewGdiDeviceName;
        query.monitor = nullptr;
        query.index = 0;

        EnumDisplayMonitors(nullptr, nullptr, [](HMONITOR monitor, HDC, LPRECT, LPARAM lparam) -> BOOL {
            MonitorQuery& query = *reinterpret_cast<MonitorQuery*>(lparam);
            MONITORINFOEXW monitor_info = {};
            monitor_info.cbSize = sizeof(monitor_info);
            GetMonitorInfoW(monitor, &monitor_info);

            if (memcmp(monitor_info.szDevice, query.device_name, CCHDEVICENAME * sizeof(WCHAR)) != 0) {
                ++query.index;
                return TRUE;
            }
            query.monitor = monitor;
            return FALSE;
        }, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&query));

        if (query.monitor) {
            printf("MONITOR[%u]: %.32ws\n", query.index + 1, target_device.monitorFriendlyDeviceName);
            printf("Handle: %llu\n", reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(query.monitor));
            printf("DevicePath: %.128ws\n", target_device.monitorDevicePath);
            puts("");
        }
    }
}
```

If you just want the display names without any additional information you don't even need the `DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_DEVICE_NAME` and `EnumDisplayMonitors` query.

**Appendix:** Some old and cheap monitors do not support the required EDID feature to return a friendly device name. This case can be detected by checking if the `monitorFriendlyDeviceName` string is of length zero.